# Sum Series Simplication

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to simplify the following formula:

$$\sum_{1\leq z < z^\prime < y\leq n} \frac{k^3}{z z^\prime y} (1 + \frac{k}{x + 1}) (1 + \frac{k}{x + 2}) \ldots (1 + \frac{k}{z - 1})(1 + \frac{k}{z + 1}) (1 + \frac{k}{z + 2}) \ldots (1 + \frac{k}{z^\prime - 1})(1 + \frac{k}{z^\prime + 1}) (1 + \frac{k}{z^\prime + 2}) \ldots (1 + \frac{k}{y - 1}).$$

I have been attempting to first simplify the product terms and then use integral to approximate the summation, however, so far I have no success. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is $x$? Are you summing over $x$? How come $x+1\leqslant z$ for every $z\geqslant1$?

Comment: Simul-posted to MO, without mention at either site: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146336/sum-series-simplication

Comment: The sign under summation is $1 \leq x < z < z^\prime < y \leq n$. Also this may be entirely ignorant of me that I was not aware of the fact that math.stackexchange and mathoverflow are against cross-post. I can totally agree that if the two have much overlapped audience, this is annoying. However is this the case?

Comment: We are not entirely against cross-posting, but we are certainly against cross-posting without informing both sites that that's what you're doing.